# Update total from checkbox data vaules

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the code that I can get to add up the value correctly, each checkbox has a data attribute value and I would like to update the total depending on what checkboxes are ticked.

At present its just displaying the values in 1 string rather then calculating the new total.

#### View

```
<input type="checkbox" onchange="checkTotal()" checked id="product-1" data-product-price="19.85">
<input type="checkbox" onchange="checkTotal()" checked id="product-2" data-product-price="17.25">
<input type="checkbox" onchange="checkTotal()" checked id="product-3" data-product-price="18.65">
<input type="checkbox" onchange="checkTotal()" checked id="product-4" data-product-price="16.35">
```

#### JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#prod1').val(true);
    $('#prod2').val(true);
    $('#prod3').val(true);
    $('#prod4').val(true);
});

function checkTotal() {
    var checks = $("input[id*='product-']");
    var tot = "68.95";
    checks.each(function () {
        var checkbox = this;
        if (checkbox.checked) {
            tot += $(this).data("product-price");
            console.log($(this).data("product-price"));
            if (checkbox.id == 'product-1') {
                $('#prod1').val(true);
            }
            if (checkbox.id == 'product-2') {
                $('#prod2').val(true);
            }
            if (checkbox.id == 'product-3') {
                $('#prod3').val(true);
            }
            if (checkbox.id == 'product-4') {
                $('#prod4').val(true);
            }
        }
        if (!checkbox.checked) {
            if (checkbox.id == 'product-1') {
                $('#prod1').val(false);
            }
            if (checkbox.id == 'product-2') {
                $('#prod2').val(false);
            }
            if (checkbox.id == 'product-3') {
                $('#prod3').val(false);
            }
            if (checkbox.id == 'product-4') {
                $('#prod4').val(false);
            }
        }
    });

    var totalSpan = $('#totalAmount');
    totalSpan.text(tot);
}
```

Comment: you can replace most of the code with id and `$("#prod1").val(checkbox.checked)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In-order to get the total price, Loop through each selected checkbox and add the data values. You can use `:selected` to get the selected checkboxes only.

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function () {
    var tot = 0;
    $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function () {
        tot += $(this).data("product-price");
    });
    var number = this.id.split("-")[1];
    $('#prod' + number).val(this.checked);
    var totalSpan = $('#totalAmount');
    totalSpan.text(tot);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/238/)

Note that, you dont have to write inline code for `change` event of the checkbox. You can bind it with jquery.

Comment: This works but how to I display a default price so all boxes are checked on page load and a value is displayed i.e. var tot = 69.85

Comment: @DanMitchell let me know the result.

Answer (score 0):

with jQuery libraries try this!
first i get the value of `data-product-price` if that checkbox is checked and store it in array
then i simply add all the value of array using loop check it below, just comment here if you dont understand i will explain it further :)
your HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked id="product-1" data-product-price="19.85">
<input type="checkbox" checked id="product-2" data-product-price="17.25">
<input type="checkbox" checked id="product-3" data-product-price="18.65">
<input type="checkbox" checked id="product-4" data-product-price="16.35">
<br>Total<input type = "text" name = "total" id = "total">
```

your JS

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    checkTotal();

    $('input[type="checkbox"]').on("click", function(){
        checkTotal();
    });
});

function checkTotal(){
    var selected = [];
    var total = 0;
    $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
        selected.push($(this).attr('data-product-price'));
    });

    for( var x = 0; x < selected.length; x++ ){
        total += selected[x] * 1;
    }

   $("#total").val(total);
}
```